# Python os.walk() get files before directories

Tags: python, find, depth, os.walk

I want to simulate the `-depth` argument of bash `find` command using python `os.walk()`.

From the Linux manual page:

```
-depth Process each directory's contents before the directory
              itself.
```

How can this be done ?

Comment: Have a look at the `topdown` parameter in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `files` or `dirs` like this:

```py
import os
root_path = r'/home/testuser/test/'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_path, topdown=True):
    print(root)
    print(dirs)
    print(files)
```

also you can walk through directories from bottom to top with `topdown=False`